# How do I start this javascript code on click

Tags: javascript

EDITED: Ok, I didn't explain well. I have added a button in the HTML. When you click that, it alerts and asks for user to enter questions and answers. BUT...it doesn't push that array into the cards themselves.

I have hacked together a simple javascript flash card program. But it starts immediately on page load. How do I make it start on click of a single `<button>`? I've tried enclosing the entire code in a function but then the user inputs that create the array don't get passed to the flashcards -- I assume because they are separate functions. I'm probably not explaining this well. But I want the entire program to run on click of one button. I appreciate any help.

```css
#flashcardFront {
    margin-top: 100px;
    margin-left: 400px;
    width: 300px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
    font-family: arial;
    font-size: 22px;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 50px 0;
    display: block;
}

a:link {
    text-decoration: none;
}

#number {
    color: red;
    position: relative;
    left: -120px;
    top: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <button onclick='cards();'>button</button>
    <a id="flashcardFront" href="#" onclick="flashCards();"></a>
</div>
```

```js
var myArray = [];                               

for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {              // # of loops 
  myArray.push(prompt('Enter question ' + (i+1))); // push the value into the array
  myArray.push(prompt('Enter answer ' + (i+1))); // push the value into the array
}
/*var myArray = [
  "Q: What's my name?", 'A: Heck no.',
  'Q: My age?', "A: Cool kids don't say.",
  'Q: Fave rocker?', 'A: Paul Gilbert'
];*/
var myIndex = 0;

function renderQuestion(index) {
  // render number if index is even
  var str = myArray[index]
  if (index % 2 == 0) {
    str += '<br><span class="question-number">' + (index / 2 + 1) + '</span>'
  }
  return str
}

function flashCards() {
  var flashcardFront = document.getElementById('flashcardFront');
  flashcardFront.innerHTML = renderQuestion(myIndex);
  myIndex = (myIndex + 1) % (myArray.length);
}

flashCards()
```

Comment: @Roizpi Semicolons aren't really required – [ASI](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Lexical_grammar#Automatic_semicolon_insertion).

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue here is that `myIndex` is a global. The first time `flashcards` runs, it increments the index to the length of the array, so the next time it runs (in the click handler) it's already at the end of the array. Set it to 0 at the beginning of `flashcards`.

Answer (score 0):

At the end of the code, you call `flashCard()` javascript function which cause your page to load the first question immediately after user entered all prompted inputs. Remove it and your application is good to go.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var questionsAndAnswers = [];     

var myIndex = 0;



function showAllQuestionsAndAnswers() {
for (var i = 0; i < questionsAndAnswers.length; i++) {
    if(i % 2 == 0) {
      alert("Question: " + questionsAndAnswers[i]);
    }
    else {
        alert("Answer: " + questionsAndAnswers[i]);
    }
}
}
/*var myArray = [
  "Q: What's my name?", 'A: Heck no.',
  'Q: My age?', "A: Cool kids don't say.",
  'Q: Fave rocker?', 'A: Paul Gilbert'
];*/


function renderQuestion(index) {
  // render number if index is even
  var str = questionsAndAnswers[index]
  if (index % 2 == 0) {
    str += '<br><span class="question-number">' + (index / 2 + 1) + '</span>'
  }
  return str
}


function flashCards() {
for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {              // # of flash cards
  questionsAndAnswers.push(prompt('Enter question ' + (i+1))); // push the value into the array
  questionsAndAnswers.push(prompt('Enter answer ' + (i+1))); // push the value into the array
  

}
  var flashcardFront = document.getElementById('flashcardFront');
  flashcardFront.innerHTML = renderQuestion(myIndex);
  myIndex = (myIndex + 1) % (questionsAndAnswers.length);
}

function startGame() {
  flashCards();
}
document.getElementById("start_game").onclick = function() {startGame()};
```

```css
#flashcardFront {
    margin-top: 100px;
    margin-left: 400px;
    width: 300px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
    font-family: arial;
    font-size: 22px;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 50px 0;
    display: block;
}

a:link {
    text-decoration: none;
}

#number {
    color: red;
    position: relative;
    left: -120px;
    top: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <button onclick='cards();'>button</button>
    <button id="start_game">
    Start Game
    </button>
    <a id="flashcardFront" href="#" onclick="flashCards();"></a>
</div>
```

Comment: Good points. But it's not passing into the cards. When you click the button it alerts for the user inputs but they don't get passed so they appear on the flashcards.

Comment: Let me look into it!

Comment: Console says myIndex is not defined but I'm stuck on how to fix that.

Comment: see the updated answer, this will give you a great start. Let me know if you have questions

Comment: Thanks. I'll take a look. I appreciate your help.

Comment: I'm still digging in to this and I'm almost understanding, but once user enters the questions/answers and the alerts are done, when you click on the flash card it doesn't flip from question to answer --- it just starts the alerts again.

Comment: that's because we have an onclick="flashCards();" event triggering when we click on the flashcardFront. You could write another function called showAnswer() and trigger it when you click on the flashcardFront

Comment: Great idea. I'll try it.

Comment: I got it working. Your answers really helped inform my solution and you're awesome. Along with what you showed me, I had a bunch of scope issues.

Comment: Thanks, glad I could help